# Unable to get rid of Email response in Codeigniter3

Tags: codeigniter, email

I am working on Codeigniter3. Now trying to send email via smtp and its working fine but my main problem is, it showing response of send email on page (if its success or error no matter). Now I am trying to find if I used print_debugger anywhere but I am not using it.

But still its email response on page. Its really very strange. I am using below code for reference.

```
$config = Array(
        'protocol' => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'your Gmail Email-ID',
        'smtp_pass' => 'your Gmail Email-password',
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'crlf' => '\r\n',
        'newline' => '\r\n',
    );

    $this->load->library('email', $config);
    //$this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from('internifi@support.com', 'Internifi');

    $this->email->to('mayankbha@gmail.com');

    $this->email->subject('Test Email Subject');

    $this->email->message('Test Email Body');

    //Send mail
    if($this->email->send()) {
        echo 'A verification link has been sent to your email account. Please click on the link and verify your account.';
    } else {
        echo 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
    }
```

Any help is really appreciated. If someone can point me right direction or may its some silly mistake but I am not able to find it.

Thanks.

Comment: What message is displayed? You could try to redirect the user after sending the email.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Actually its on registration page and once user gets success message then in controller I send message and show success message. And it shows the message about success email sent using SMTP, all info that we get when we use print_debugger() to show email response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After email functionality, you can redirect the user to the Login page or any other page you want.

you can use `$this->session->set_flashdata` to store success or error message and display it on view page after redirect.

```
//Send mail
if($this->email->send()) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success','A verification link has been sent to your email account. Please click on the link and verify your account.');
    redirect('user/login', 'refresh'); //For example. Please use your controller name.
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('error','There is an Error in sending email. Please contact Site Management.');
    redirect('user/register', 'refresh'); //For example. Please use your controller name.
}
```

And in the View, you can display this flashdata message.

Comment: I am using email when user register. So I first register the user then send the email to verify account and show the success message on register page itself.

Comment: Before this email functionality, insert user's registration details in database and set user's status to 'inactive'. And when user clicks on verification link, change user status to 'active'.  You can show this flash_message on any page. It will be shown only 1 time. So after registration user will be redirected to Login page and sees the verification link message. Then user clicks on verification link and returns to Login page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've done the same and its working.

Comment: Hello I tried this solution on linux server and it was showing header already sent error as well as email response so I applied ob_start on index.php main file. After this it redirects to login but meanwhile it still shows the header already sent and email response and then it redirects to login in few seconds. It looks awkward. Any suggestion to overcome this behavior.